# How to use a variable created by a javascript function in a hidden field?

Tags: javascript, forms, variables, illegal-characters, formmail

I'm using a feature from formmail.php which allows me to use a hidden input that will rename a file uploaded by the user. This way I can keep the value of the real company name while removing illegal characters from the composed file name.

I've written a function that would do the proper replacements and assign the new value to a string variable, so I could use at the hidden input. Like this:

```
<input type="text" id="CompanyName" name="CompanyName" size="60" maxlength="40" onchange="clean(this.value)" required>

<script type="text/javascript">
 cleanName = "";  // variable outside the function meant to be Global
 function clean()
 {
 cleanName = document.getElementById("CompanyName").value.replace(/[/\\/'"*&%$]/g, "");
 }
 </script>
```

Nevertheless, when I try to use that "cleanName" variable, its value appears empty:

```
<input type="hidden" name="file_names" value="Proof=State.%2D%.cleanName.%'-Paymnt'%.%2D%.Proof" />
```

The file is uploaded as "NY--Paymnt-FileName.pdf".

How can I make this work?

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to use the `cleanName` variable? As the value of the hidden input?

Comment: As I quoted above, inside the hidden input:
'<input type="hidden" name="file_names" value="Proof=State.%2D%.cleanName.%'-Paymnt'%.%2D%.Proof" />'

This works properly if I use the original company name, like this:
`<input type="hidden" name="file_names" value="Proof=State.%2D%.CompanyName.%'-Paymnt'%.%2D%.Proof />`

Comment: You are missing the closing double quotes `"` on your `value` attribute. Not sure if that's affecting your results. trincots answer below will definitely do what you're looking for.

Comment: That was mistyped, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You have just put the literal `cleanName` in an attribute value, not the value of the variable carrying that name.

You could write to the `value` attribute of the hidden input.

For that you should give your hidden input an `id`, like `id=file_names` (same as `name`).

Then change the script to this (forget the global variable):

```
function clean() {
     var cleanName = document.getElementById("CompanyName").value
                             .replace(/[/\\/'"*&%$]/g, "");
     cleanName = "Proof=State.%2D%." + cleanName + ".%'-Paymnt'%.%2D%.Proof";
     console.log(cleanName);
     document.getElementById("file_names").value = cleanName
 }
```

The HTML for the hidden input can go without a value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="file_names" id="file_names">
```

NB: I have no idea what you are going to do with that value; it looks strange, but I expect you know what you are doing on the server side.

Comment: Thanks, trincot, but it didn't work. 

The odd is I know the function is running. I've added an `alert(cleanName);` inside the function and the var showed correctly. But it is still empty when used as a string operand.

FYI, I need the replacement because some companies uses slashes in their names. Such as "LewLara/TBWA". And this creates a mess if I literally rename a file as "LewLara/TBWA-filename,pdf".

Comment: I split the assignment into parts so you can alert (or better console.log) the final value just before it gets assigned to the input. Don't forget the input must have the `file_names` id. It should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion to split the code and check the log out. That's how I found out what was going on! Since the log showed `Proof=State.%2D%.LewLaraTBWA.%'-Paymnt'%.%2D%.Proof`, I've ashamedly noticed the problem is not here, but inside formmail.php. I don't have to manipulate the value of the hidden input file_names, but to inform formmail.php that it needs to use my new variable 'cleanName' at the operation!! You see? So I've added a line `<input type="hidden" name="cleanName" id="cleanName" />` and assigned its value inside the function. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

When you call the function clean(), you pass in a variable "this.value" but the function itself does not take any argument. Either introduce an argument or stop calling clean() with an argument.

Comment: Thanks yovsky! I'm new to javascript programming. I'll change that.

Answer (score 0):

Since I found out what was going on, I'm adding this information for those who might have the same problem using formmail.php.

When using the facility of renaming a file that will be uploaded, you really need to define the hidden input "file_names" value as the parameter formmail.php will use. Such as:

```
<input type="hidden" name="file_names" value="Proof=State.%2D%.cleanName.%'-Paymnt'%.%2D%.Proof" />
```

The problem is when a user types illegal characters such as a backslash, that can't be used in a filename.

So, in my example, to strip those illegal characters from a variable and create another variable I can use elsewhere through a javascript function, I just defined a new hidden input, like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cleanName" id="cleanName" />
```

Then I called the function when the user typed the value that will be modified:

```
<input type="text" id="CompanyName" name="CompanyName" size="60" maxlength="40" onchange="clean()" required>
```

This way I can have two values from an unique user input with the javascript function, like this (assignement splited):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function clean()
 {
 var newName = document.getElementById("CompanyName").value.replace(/[/\\/'"*&%$]/g, "");
 document.getElementById("cleanName").value = newName;
 }
</script>
```

I hope this can be helpful to someone else.